# div overlay disables google maps function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-maps

I'm making a website where I want to show search results on top af a googleMaps.
I want to make it possible to scroll through these search results when the cursor is over the search results or when the cursor is over the map. I implemented this fine by making a div-structure like this:

```
<div class="map" id="parent"  >
  <div id="googleMap"></div>
  <div id="mapContainer">
    <div id="searchContainer">
      <!-- searchresults -->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I disabled the scroll-functionality in googleMaps. I still would like to drag the map, but that isn't possible because of the div laying over it. How could I solve this?

My work is visible here: http://www.veylau.be/testzone/wcb/searchtwee.html
(click the searchbutton for a better view)

There are still some positioning problems, don't mind them, they'll be solved after this problem.

Thanks in advance for helping me out! I really appreciate this!

Comment: Remove z-index of div(#mapContainer)..

Comment: Googlemaps sitting under the mapContainer , you have to change html structure

Comment: Have you tried changing the width of the mapContainer so that it doesn't cover the map? Try and apply `col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-5` to `#mapContainer`

Comment: Thanks for your help guys! @Pradeep Pansari: Removing the z-index of #mapContainer does allow me to interact with the map again. However I cannot scroll through my search results anymore when my cursor is over the map.

Mathias: that also doesn't allow me to scroll through my results. (Or I'm doing it wrong :/ )

Answer (score 1):

To allow for the interaction with the map, you will need to uncover portions of the map that are currently being covered by the search portion.

If you change padding-top to margin-top on #mapContainer, you will see that above your search element, the map is now accessible. You will need to also reduce the width of the search area to allow for access on the sides. Essentially, you'll want to use something similar to margin:0 auto; to center the block so the sides aren't covered by the "invisible" portion of the search block block as would be the case if either padding or width was defined to achieve a similar appearance.

If you are looking to keep the the map from zooming in and out even if the user isn't over the search block, you will need to use javascript to ensure all mouse-scrolls within the .map element will target the search block and not use it's default functionality, which would be either zooming in/out the map or scrolling the block depending on the location of the cursor.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I tried to catch the scroll event via Jquery, and now it's already possible to make the search results scroll. However, it's not only the search results which are scrolling, it's the entire site :( How can I solve this? www.veylau.be/testzone/wcb2/searchtwee.html

Comment: I'm glad it's progressing. You can include event.preventDefault(); to your scroll function to disable the default scrolling action that's scrolling the entire page. You'd add it inside $(window).scroll(function(event){ ... });.

Answer (score 0):

In CSS or in Inline Style of id="mapContainer", remove postion:Absolute property and check the output.

I hope it'll resolve your issue.